# Binding td in table using function call javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a `td` which contains image data which I will add when I calling a function. The function I am returning td with image data, I get blank row only.

[image]

```
 var html = "";
     html += "<td>" + country + "</td>";
     html += "<td>" + gender + "</td>";
     html += "<td>" + meal + "</td>";
     html+=  load_image(img);
     html += "<td>" + doc + "</td>";
 document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += html;
```

function

```
  function load_image(ref)  
  { 
    var array = ref.split(',');
    var html = "";
    return "<td>";
                 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                  var src = "uploads/"+ array[i];
                  var img1 = '<img src='+ src +' height="42" width="42">';
                         return img1
                   }
            html += "</td>";
    return html;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML`.

Here is a sample:

```
function load_image(image_src, parentElement){
   //image_src is your image's path
   //parentElement is your <td> which you want to put an image into it
   var newImage = document.createElement('img');
   newImage.src = image_src;
   newImage.style.width = "300px";
   newImage.style.height = "300px";
   parentElement.appendChild(newImage);
}

var elem = document.getElementById("data");   //This your parent element, i.e. <td>

load_image("some_image.jpg", elem);
```

Comment: i am fresher to JS please provide complete code so i get solution